# Аналог Java StandardPasswordEncoder в PHP

Tags: php, java, spring, хеширование, sha256

Добрый день.
Появилась тут одна задачка, переписать backend одного сайта на PHP (сейчас написан на Java). Дело в том, что авторизация пользователей (а точнее хеш пароля) сейчас высчитывается посредством метода 
     passwordEncoder.encode(password); 
в Java. Сохраненный хеш хранится в БД, имеет длину 80 символов. Например, для пароля "12345" хеш будет "d0cf091711a1c35d5fac40ad8c522223365c7a7f286aa56d7ab80a11adaf7cfe2d1a9b91a5680080".
Может знает кто, есть ли на PHP аналогичная функция хеширования? Буду очень признателен :)
P.S. Судя по описанию метода, Java хеширует пасс посредством SHA-256, но если применить его в PHP, то на выходе имеем строку всего в 64 символа.
P.P.S Для этого метода используется springframework

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder;

public class NewClass {
    private static StandardPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new StandardPasswordEncoder();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String password = "12345";
        String hash = passwordEncoder.encode(password);

        System.out.println(hash);
    }
}
```

Comment: *A standard {@code PasswordEncoder} implementation that uses SHA-256 hashing with 1024 iterations **and a random 8-byte random salt value.***

Comment: Версия PHP какая?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.password-hash.php

Comment: надо написать на PHP 7